# How to apply the word2vec model to text file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I trained word2vec model from my corpus.

```
corpus = "fewdata.txt"
f = io.open(corpus, mode ="r", encoding = "utf-8")
#corpus1 = list(f) 
lines = f.readlines()
sentences =[]
for line in lines:
    mqul= line.split()
    #print(mqul)
    sentences.append(mqul)
model = Word2Vec(sentences = sentences, size = 100, sg = 1, window = 3, min_count = 1, iter = 10, workers = Pool()._processes)
model.init_sims(replace = True)
model.save('model.bin')
model = Word2Vec.load('model.bin')
print(model)
```

then

```
model['aImIroawi']
array([-0.06561889, -0.15222837,  0.00912119, -0.11638119, -0.03242991,
       -0.13457145, -0.09813376,  0.07011288,  0.0711898 ,  0.10069774,
       -0.01028561,  0.11995316,  0.03737569, -0.01811702, -0.12935248],
      dtype=float32)
```

but i want to use this model for the txt file with 5333 vocabulary and save it to txt file in the form of

```
{ 'Aimurawi : array([-0.04728228,  0.13645388,  0.13822217,  0.13086553, -0.0963688 ],dtype= float32),
 Tiona : array([-0.04728228,  0.13645388,  0.13822217,  0.13086553, -0.0963688 ], dype =float32)}
```

for all the vocabulary in my text file, can anybody help me how i can do it?

Comment: The `Word2Vec` model's `.wv` property already contains a dict-like object which allows looking up any word & receiving its array. So it's very easy to loop over any list of words, perhaps exactly the list of words in the model, and get/print each vector. But why do you want it in that particular format – which looks a lot like, but doesn't seem to be exactly, Python print-strings for a dictionary? And do you want each known word printed exactly once, in any order? Or just the words from some other file, in the order in the file, possibly including duplicates?

Comment: yes i was looking exactly that  i but thanks i did it. and save it to text file. now i am looking for any word respective array from my text file  like => word = "cat" , s = data.get(word) and yield the array of cat like [0.23088 0.28283 0.6318 .......].

Comment: Once you have (or have saved and reloaded) the `.wv` object, then `wv['cat']` will give you the vector (as a `numpy` array) for the word 'cat'. Or are you asking for something else?